# export 'partition' was not found in 'rxjs'

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, rxjs

I am trying to use ng-http-loader in my angular project. I have installed ng-http-loader package. While compilation of project i am getting an error. The error is

> export 'partition' was not found in 'rxjs'.

**package.json**:

```js
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^8.2.2",
  "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.3",
  "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
  "@angular/material": "^8.1.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "ng-http-loader": "^6.0.1",
  "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
  "tslib": "^1.9.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
```

Comment: can you show your package.json?

Comment: You can [edit] your question, please don't post code in comments

Comment: Reproduce the error on stackblitz this issue happens with RxJS version lower than 6.5.0 and yours is higher than that.

Comment: Upgrading RxJS version to 6.5.3 worked for me. `npm i rxjs@6.5.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to ng-http-loader.js. And you could see the following

```
import { ReplaySubject,partition, merge, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, switchMap, debounce, distinctUntilChanged, tap} from 
'rxjs/operators';
```

You just have to change them to this :

```
import { ReplaySubject, merge, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, switchMap, debounce, distinctUntilChanged, tap, partition } 
from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-http-loader.js hasn't such that importings